# Prestashop Error baseUri

Tags: javascript, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I develop my theme from the default theme default-bootstrap. But an error occurs when I try to add an item to my cart.

[image]

You have an idea of where it might come ?

Comment: Have you make some changes to `global.tpl` or `layout.tpl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JS var `baseUri` is declared in `global.tpl`, check if you have made some 'wrong' changes to `global.tpl` or `layout.tpl`.

Original value of that var is declared in FrontController.php that give to smarty the value with a var named `base_uri`, then in `global.tpl` that var become `baseUri` for JS.